# How to Check if elements of two lists are equal to the 3rd list

Tags: python

I have this code:

```
list1 = [1,2,3]
list2 = [3,4,5]
list3 = []


for i, j in zip(list1,list2):
    if i==j:
        list3 = i,j
```

How can I make `list3` store elements that are the same between `list1` and `list2`?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and note that this is *not a discussion forum*. I tried to edit your question to ask it clearly, according to what I understand. To be clear: you want the result `list3` to be `[3]`, yes? Even though the `3`s are in different positions in the source lists?

Comment: Hello and yes and this is the result i want to get to but according to mylittle knowledge in pytone i dont figuring it out how can it can be done

Comment: and sorry for this answers im new in this by the way

Comment: Good, that's all the information I needed. Please see the linked duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way using Python's [`set intersection`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.intersection):

```
list1 = [1,2,3]
list2 = [3,4,5]
list3 = list(set(list1).intersection(list2))

print(list3)
```

or using a `for loop`:

```
list1 = [1,2,3]
list2 = [3,4,5]
list3 = []
for i in list1:
    if i in list2:
        list3.append(i)

print(list3)
```

Comment: if you will use this technique in single for loop, will it work?

Comment: @DANKEST Hi, take a look at my updated answer and let me know if that is what you are looking for.

Comment: it is helpful but im looking for only using one [for loop] and only one 'in'  operator

Comment: You should have specified that condition in your question.